# Difference query but same result

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query has to return : ID Order, amount of items in that Order, show just top one,.

First query i did by myself second is from tips. Both gave me same result.

So my ask is : My solution is wrong with that query or just show how iam beginner and made so bad things.

The think is I don't understand why i should to go for Join two tables in that query if i can call from just one table

Work on dataBase 'adventureWorks2012'

My query:

```
Select  Top 1
   SalesOrderID,
   COUNT(*) as Items
From 
   Sales.SalesOrderDetail
Group By 
   SalesOrderID
Order BY 
   Items DESC
```

Solution:

```
Select Top 1
   H.SalesOrderID,
   Count(*) as AmountItems
From 
   Sales.SalesOrderHeader As H JOIN SAles.SalesOrderDetail As D
      ON H.SalesOrderID = D.SalesOrderID
Group by 
   H.SalesOrderID
Order BY 
COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: do the fact that the columns related  to the table SalesOrderHeader are not necessary  .. you can simply use a single table and avoid the join ... you must only be sure that the column ProductID is not null ... could be is better using count(*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine.  In fact, it is better than the other query, assuming that all values of `SalesOrderID` are in `SalesOrderHeader`.  This is a very reasonable assumption (and it can be guaranteed if the  a foreign key constraint has been defined).

You are also using an alias for the `ORDER BY`.  That is another plus.

I think your query is simpler, faster, and shows a reasonable knowledge of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID is a foreign key to SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID then the referential integrity is ensured.  So in that case, it can be done without a join to SalesOrderHeader. And just group on SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID

```
SELECT TOP 1
 d.SalesOrderID, 
 COUNT(*) as AmountItems
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail d
GROUP BY d.SalesOrderID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

But if SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID wouldn't be a  foreign key? And you only want to count for SalesOrderID that actually exist in SalesOrderHeader? Then joining to SalesOrderHeader would assure that.

```
SELECT TOP 1
 d.SalesOrderID, 
 COUNT(*) as AmountItems
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail d
JOIN SalesOrderHeader h ON h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY d.SalesOrderID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

So assuming that SalesOrderID is the primary key for SalesOrderHeader. [It is](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc//browse-sql-doc/TestServer/User_databases/AdventureWorks2012/Tables/SalesOrderHeader.html). 
 And SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID is a foreign key to SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID. [It is](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc//browse-sql-doc/TestServer/User_databases/AdventureWorks2012/Tables/SalesOrderDetail.html).
Then your first query is a-ok.